# Need OS Name and then Version

Tags: vbscript

I need to retrieve the operating system name such as "Windows 2003" and then OS Version, which would be "Server Standard Edition".

I have this script

```
Set colItems = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
For Each objOperatingSystem in colItems
   strOSName = objOperatingSystem.Caption
Next
```

This makes strOSName as "Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition" or on the system I am developing in "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional".

Is there a way for me to break these two aspects apart? If that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marketing has a say in versioning, I doubt that you can find a generally applicable strategy for all windows versions. For the examples given, I'd start with a RegExp:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim aVers : aVers = Array( _
    "Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition" _
  , "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" _
)
Dim reVers : Set reVers = New RegExp
reVers.Pattern = "^(\D+\d+) (.*)$"
Dim sVers
For Each sVers In aVers
    Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reVers.Execute(sVers)
    WScript.Echo Join(Array( _
       qq(sVers), qq(oMTS(0).SubMatches(0)), qq(oMTS(0).SubMatches(1)) _
    ), vbCrLf)
Next
```

output:

```
"Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition"
"Windows 2003"
"Server Standard Edition"
"Microsoft Windows 7 Professional"
"Microsoft Windows 7"
"Professional"
```

To cope with e.g. "Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]" you'll have to tinker with the pattern (but customizing a RegExp pattern scales better than modifying a function containing lots of InStr() and Mid() calls).

**ADDED** /cf. comment)

The pattern "^(\D+\d+) (.*)$" looks for:

1. ^ start of string
2. ( begin first capture/group
3. \D+ sequence (1 or more) non-digits
4. \d+ sequence of digitis
5. ) end first capture/group
6. <-- look! a blank!
7. ( begin second capture/group
8. .* (possibly empty) sequence of characters except vbLf
9. ) end second capture/group
10. $ end of string

Comment: That worked great. I know a bit of regexp, but I don't see what your pattern is doing. I mean, its working and this is great but I'm just curious.

Comment: I have a batch file that does this. I would suggest looking at powershell for the best way.